# Why Url without http or https not open in webkit

Tags: swift, webview

Here is the code implementation

```
let url = URL(string: "www.google.com")
 webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

**Error**
The URL can’t be shown

Comment: Did You check if url is not nil? Try to add `https://`when creating the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Https stands for Hyper Text Transfer protocol. It is used for communication between the client and the website server database. You can't connect to a website until and unless you communicate with it. In normal surfing, the browser adds https automatically for us in URL if it is not there but in the dev environment, you have to manually add it.